# Creating a Forms Authentication cookie for a search engine crawler

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, roles

Big picture: I have been asked to create a search engine for our company's intranet.  Such a search engine will crawl pages supplied to it by XML files for each independent application on the intranet.  Problem is, the entire intranet is using Forms Authentication, and so the crawler will have to have access to each application without actually having user credentials (e.g. username and password).

Each application within the intranet has its access controlled by a permission manager, which is essentially a wrapper on the default Role Manager ASP.NET comes with.  Each application can define its own roles and assign people who have those roles.

Please note that there are potentially hundreds of applications.

The crawler has access to the permission manager's database, so it knows what all the roles are.  Therefore my idea was to have the crawler create a cookie that identifies it as having all roles for each application.

The problem I'm running into is this: how do I create a forms authentication cookie which already has the roles assigned in it without creating a corresponding user (IPrincipal).

It is entirely possible that I've failed to completely understand how Forms Authentication works, and if so, please tell me what I can do differently.

Comment: Do you use claims based authentication for all your applications or does each application handle its own authentication?

Comment: Are the apps you want to crawl all on the same machine as the crawler, or do you need to cross machine boundaries?

Comment: What kind of cookie will be set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably not what you want to hear, but...

I would just have the crawler authenticate like anyone else.

Given that this is a crawler you control, why fight Forms Authentication?  Seems logical to create a user with all required roles in each application (hopefully you have a central administration point for the hundreds of apps, else I would not want to be an administrator there ;-)

If you do anything that allows "just the crawler" special access (bypass user-based authentication based on... what?  The crawler's user agent?  A specific origin IP?), you create a security hole that a hacker can leverage to gain access to all of the intranet applications that have otherwise been diligently secured with user IDs, passwords and roles (in fact, the security hole is particularly wide because you propose granting access to EVERY role in the system).

Comment: The other benefit of @Eric J.'s suggestion is that you don't want you crawler to index "private" stuff and then show it in the search results for user who lacks permission to see such "private" stuff. By having it authenticate at the user level you desire it will see exactly what a user at that level will see. If you give it some "god mode" authentication cookie you could get in trouble later when role/permissions get changed on you where a user account would be just fine.

Comment: @BenSwayne we got around the "god mode" problem by controlling what the crawler crawls; it has a list of locations for sitemaps, and only crawls pages in those sitemaps.  Plus, it can impersonate a user to query a result using the search's authentication cookie to determine if the searcher has access to the page.

Comment: @MatthewJones: How are you going to keep that sitemap updated across hundreds of applications over time?  The apps already use roles to map out who has access to what.  Your sitemap will have to be constantly maintained with essentially the same information.  Also, what if some pages display different/additional content only to certain users (e.g. in Finance role also show salary...)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is an appropriately encrypted System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket (which then gets attached to HTTP requests as a cookie).

The encryption logic is located in System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(), which I think uses the MachineKey as the encryption key. Also have a look at the GetAuthCookie() logic (using Reflector).

You might have to write your own version of the encryption method, but what you want to do should be possible, provided you have a copy of the remote site's encryption keys. You don't need the user's passwords -- only the user name is encoded into the Ticket.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem is not yet well defined, (at least to me!).
Why do you need to crawl the pages and index them if there are fine grained permissions on them?! How do you show search results without violating the permissions? Why not index the back end by passing the pages altogether (I mean index the database records not the pages)....

Comment: "How do you show search results without violating permissions?" You have to be logged in to use the search, so when a user searches, we check the first ten results by taking his login cookie and using it to query the result page.  If we get back a 404, or the login page, or an error page, we assume the user does not have access and we remove that result from the list; it never gets shown to the user.